# Popstate Issue In Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs, spring

Hi Have a below code to implement a logic in while clicking back button

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
 var location = document.location;
 if (history.state && typeof history.state.selectedVariantColor != 'undefined') {
  var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + history.state.selectedVariantColor;
        window.location.replace(url);
 } 
 else {
  window.location.href = location;
 }
});
```

I want this code to run only when back button is clicked and not in any other scenario. But In chrome this code is getting executed repeatedly on every action (issue not replicable in FireFox)

Can anyone please suggest a work around for this.
I want the code block to work only when back button is clicked.